# Difference between two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Hi friends this piece of code is not returning the correct time difference between two times instead returning NaN can any one spot the mistake in my code , thanks in advance .

```
$("[id^='endTime']").change(function(){
var index = $(this).attr('id').slice(7);
var startTime = $('#startTime'+index).val();
var endTime = $(this).val();
    var result = (new Date(startTime.val) - new Date(endTime.val));
alert(parseInt(result , 10));

$('#result'+index).val(parseInt(endTime , 10) - parseInt(startTime , 10)); ;
```

Comment: Why haven't you stepped through this code with a debugger? Why are you trying to get the `val` property of a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.val` from `new Date(startTime.val)` and `new Date(endTime.val)`.